# Websites in AngularJS for automation purposes

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm looking for websites written in AngularJS to practice my automation skills (using Protractor).
Protractor has features to locate elements using `ng-repeater`, `ng-model`, `ng-bind`, etc.
I've tried to find websites written in AngularJS but none of them really uses features like repeater, model, binding...  (At least you can't see it in DevTools).
Hope you can help me find relevant websites for my purpose :)

Comment: hey @Askish, can you accept the answer since there is no better ones, otherwise your 50 points will be wasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These:

- https://www.jetblue.com/
- https://www.freelancer.com/
- https://www.istockphoto.com/
- https://goodfil.ms/
- https://rozetka.com.ua/

Or just lookup `angular templates online preview` and you'll get portals like this

- https://angular-templates.io/product/angular-admin-template/full-preview